# angular component not showing in index file

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I'm trying to work my way through Valerio De Sanctis book on .netcore and angular 2 and haven't been able to get past chapter 1. I'm using VS 2017 and battling with changes in newer library versions e.g. if using typescript 2 and above you no longer need to reference typings, well that what I read.

I've probably missed something crucial but I'm at the point where it should work, however when i run it, I do not see  the angular component appear in the html page.

I have put the project on my github: https://github.com/Duntless83/.NetCoreTutorial

What have I done wrong?